# Additional boards manager option is missing from Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am new to Arduino. For the project I am trying to do, I want to install the ESP8266 extension. But the additional boards manager URL option is missing from the Arduino IDE. What should I do to add the extension?

Comment: Update to a version that has the option.

Comment: I just installed the ide 2 days ago . I have the latest one.

Comment: What version do you have that you think is the latest one?

Comment: Version of installed ide is 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4

Comment: 1.0.5 is ancient.

Answer (score 9):

You need to download and install a recent version of the Arduino IDE from:

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

When you install the Arduino IDE using `apt-get` you get a very outdated and non-standard version, which does not have the Boards Manager feature. The reason for this is that the license documentation of the Arduino IDE does not currently meet the required standards for the package manager:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2703

Answer (score 1):

the URL is the following and the 1.8.2 IDE accepted it: 
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json

Good luck,
endre

P.s.: I found the answer/URL here:
[No Response to AT commands](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/no-response-to-at-commands/31297#31297)

Comment: this worked....actually this is the correct url

Answer (score 0):

You stated in the comments that you are using version 1.0.5. This is a very old version. Go through you computer and make sure you uninstalled any old versions, then try to reinstall the ide.

Make sure you download from [arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc), the official location to download the software.